# How to make this code responsive?

Tags: html, css

```css
.intro-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #449bb5;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}


.ham-layer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}


#nav-icon {
    position: fixed;
    left: 35px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 20px;

    margin: 50px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1001;
}

#nav-icon span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 9px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon.open span {
    background: #111111;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -1px;
  left: 1px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 22px;
  left: 2px;
}

.ham-layer.open {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale(100);
    -ms-transform: scale(100);
    transform: scale(100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .8s all ease;
    transition: .8s all ease;
    z-index: 1000;

}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="ham-layer"></div>
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-bars hamburger"></i> -->
                    <div id="nav-icon">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <p id="_intro" class="text-center">Darth Vader</p>
                    <hr width=40%>
                    <p id="belowIntro" class="text-center">Interactive Portfolio</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is my code-snippet for a section in html. The problem is that the section is not responsive. Specifically, when the screen is made small, it scrolls horizontally and shows white space. What is the reason for this?
How can I make this section responsive?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in given code - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bEXZVW

Answer (score 4):

You can make your page responsive by using media-queries in your css.

Here is a tutorial that will get you started:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

---

A media Query Template from Bootstrap:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: can you please make changes to this html. Will help me understand faster

Comment: haha, I was just writing an answer with exactly the same link and almost the same text! Yes, media queries are a good solution!

Comment: haha, @darthvader, are you seriously think people will help you with the homework?

Comment: OP is already using bootstrap, which comes with responsive. so no need for that